# How to get all descendants of a node

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NodeTest] (
[Id]             INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[NodeCode]       NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[ParentNodeCode] NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
[NodeName]       NVARCHAR (255) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And the following data:

```
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('0', null, 'ROOT')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('01', '0', '01')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('02', '0', '02')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('03', '0', '03')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('011', '01', '011')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('012', '01', '012')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('021', '02', '021')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('022', '02', '022')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('023', '02', '023')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('024', '02', '024')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('025', '02', '025')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('031', '03', '031')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('032', '03', '032')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('0111', '011', '0111')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('0112', '011', '0112')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('0311', '031', '0311')
insert into NodeTest(NodeCode, ParentNodeCode, NodeName) values('0322', '032', '0322')
```

How can I write a view to list nodes with their all descendants? For example, for node 01 I will get:

```
01 011
01 012
01 0111
01 0112
```

Use this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7eb0), which contains the table and information presented above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a common table expression (CTE)

```
declare @parentCode varchar(20) = '01'

;with cte as 
(
    select * from NodeTest where ParentNodeCode = @parentCode
    union all
    select NodeTest.* 
    from NodeTest
         inner join cte on cte.NodeCode = nodeTest.ParentNodeCode
)
select @parentCode, nodeCode from cte;
```

Answer (score 3):

Working [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7826c/4)

I think you want this

```
with cte as 
    (
        select * from NodeTest where ParentNodeCode = '01'
        union all
        select NodeTest.* 
        from NodeTest
        inner join cte  on cte.NodeCode = NodeTest.ParentNodeCode
    )
    select * from cte;
```

Comment: What is `compartments` in your query?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu sorry it was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The query below should do the trick, basically you have to join to table back to itself to create the Parent-Child relationship and join on the Parents.NodeCode with the Childs.ParentNodeCode

```
SELECT 
    P.NodeCode,
    C.NodeCode AS ChildNodeCode
FROM
    NodeTest P
INNER JOIN
    NodeTest C
ON
    P.NodeCode = C.ParentNodeCode
```

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu it doesn't work in SQLfiddle because I had not labelled the columns differently. the query is correct.

Comment: This is what your query returns: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7eb0/18 which is not the same as the expected output.

Comment: You query only goes one level down. While it will work for a subset of data, it does not traverse the entire tree.

Comment: @podiluska yes I did not see there were multi-levels, did wonder why people where using a common table expression for what I could see as being a simple query.

Answer (score 0):

this will work

select a.NodeCode,b.NodeName  from NodeTest a inner join 
NodeTest b on a.NodeName = b.ParentNodeCode